# Let $T: V \to V$ be a linear map such that $T^2-3T+2I=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

Let $T: V \to V$ be a linear map such that $T^2-3T+2I=0$, where $I$ is the identity map.

question:

a) Prove that $V=\ker(T-2I) \oplus\ker(T-I)$

b) let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix such that $A^2-3A+2I_n=0$ Where $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix. True or false: $A$ is diagonalizable

I attempted $\ker(T-2I)=(T-2I)V=0$

$\ker(T-I)=(T-I)V=0$

I know the direct sum should be the join of $\ker(T-2T)$ and $\ker(T-I)$ is $0$, and I am not sure how to prove it

I am a first year student from McGill U. I am doing linear mapping on linear algebra. The textbook I am using is Linear Algebre edition sixth by SEYMOUR LIPAXHUTZ

Comment: Ive voted to close. Note that that $T^2-3T+2I=(T-2I)(T-I)$

Comment: I know T2−3T+2I=(T−2I)(T−I) , but how to prove the direct sum?

Comment: Okay, thx for letting me know

Comment: i'm so sorry about the confusion, it is my first post and i will learn how to use it in the future

Comment: thank you so much for the editing!

Comment: no problem. I think you mean $\ker T=\{v \in V \mid Tv=0\}$.

Comment: i don't understand how to attempt this question either. yes! and i am confused about the relationship between Ker(T-2I) and Ker(T-I) and T

Comment: A bit more information will help the readers to write answers: what book are you working on? Which section is this exercise from? It could be done using minimal polynomials.

Comment: added! thx for helping

Comment: @AndresMejia why vote to close? This isn't a horrible opening question.

Comment: @TheCount I've since retracted my close vote and voted +1 (as one should do when a question is improved :) )

Answer (score 2):

Some hints: To show $V= \ker(T-2I) \oplus \ker(T-I)$, you need to show that

(i) $\ker(T - 2I) \cap \ker(T - I) = \{0\}$ and (ii) $\ker(T - 2I) + \ker(T - I) = V$.

(i) Given $v \in \ker(T - 2I) \cap \ker(T - I)$, what can you say about $T(v)$? What does $v \in \ker(T - I)$ imply? What does $v \in \ker(T - 2I)$ imply?

(ii) Given $v \in V$, then
$$
0 = (T^2 - 3T + 2I)(v) = (T - 2I)((T - I)(v)) = (T-2I)(T(v) - v) \, .
$$
What does this say about $T(v) - v$? Similarly,
$$
0 = (T^2 - 3T + 2I)(v) = (T - I)((T - 2I)(v)) = (T-I)(T(v) - 2v) \, .
$$
What does this say about $T(v) - 2v$?

Comment: Yeah It works perfectly. Now we can clearly see $v=(Tv-v)-(Tv-2v)$

Comment: thx for helping me for the first question.

Comment: for the second one, is it okay if i proved that there are two distinct eigenvalues, so A is diagonalizable?

Comment: It is, I don't know if you have covered this or not. It's minimal polynomial factors into distinct linear polynomials, so it is diagonalisable. Otherwise you can directly see $v\in Ker(T-I)\Rightarrow Tv=v$, so v has eigenvalue 1 if nonzero, same argument goes for if a nonzero $v\in Ker(T-2I)$ to show it has eigenvalue 2

Comment: @AnqiLuo I don't think so. You would have to know that there are $n$ distinct eigenvalues (where $n$ is the dimension of $V$) in order to conclude that $T$ is diagonalizable. Or as PSG says, if you know that being diagonalizable is equivalent to the minimal polynomial being squarefree, that provides an alternate approach.

Comment: @AnqiLuo that argument works in dimension $2$ only. For PSG's suggestion please consult these excellent notes http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/minpolyandappns.pdf

Comment: okay! thanks everyone for helping!!

Comment: @AnqiLuo Did you figure out how to use my hint for part (ii)? You can solve this problem without using the theory of minimal polynomials.

Comment: @André3000 could you explain that a little bit? Thank you!

Comment: @AnqiLuo Okay, let $w = T(v) - v$. Then my first equation shows that $(T-2I)(w) = 0$. What does that say about $w$ (and $T-2I)$?

Comment: @André3000 w=o?

Comment: @AnqiLuo No, we don't necessarily have $w = 0$. Maybe something to do with kernels...?

Comment: @André3000 lol okay. so (T-2I) is the kernel of V?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85361/discussion-between-andre-3000-and-anqi-luo).

Answer (score -1):

Spanning part is already proved. Now, say $v\in ker (T-2I)\cap ker (T-I)$. Then $(T-2I)v=0$

$\Rightarrow (T-I)v=v $

$\Rightarrow v=0$

Comment: thank you for answering! how did you get (T-I)v=v?

Comment: (T-I-I)v=0  , => (T-I)v- Iv=0 => (T-I)v=Iv=v

Comment: Notice that I is identity map and all the maps are linear. So steps are justified. Hope it helps.

Comment: oh okay, do we have to prove that the addition on the two gives V?

Comment: "Spanning part is already proved." Where is this proved exactly?

Comment: In the other comments , ppl showed that $T^2-3T+2I=(T-2I)(T-I)=0$, so for any $v\in V$, $v\in ker(T-2I)$ or $v\in ker(T-I)$. So, $V=ker(T-2I)+ker(T-I)$

Comment: @PSG I don't see how it follows from that factorization. And what you say cannot strictly be true: $v$ could very well be a sum of a vector $v_1 \in \ker(T - 2I)$ and a vector $v_2 \in \ker(T - I)$. From $0 = (T-2I)(T-I)(v) = (T- 2I)(T(v) - v)$, all one can say is that $(T-I)(v) \in \ker(T - 2I)$ (and similarly $(T-2I)(v) \in \ker(T-I)$).

Comment: oh. I see,yeah there is a problem.We can argue like $(x-2)(x-1)$ annihilates $V$, So, there are 3 options for the minimal polynomial. As $(x-2)$ and $(x-1)$ are different prime factors of the PID $k[X]$, all the three will conclude the spanning part.

Comment: PSG, OP is a first year student in linear algebra, you should rephrase your argument (PID structure) maybe using jordan block or something along those lines @André3000 I stank I can.

Comment: @AndresMejia You're smelcome. :)